# How to split one column into two columns just by counting the characters and inserting them into another table via a SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to select the first 2 char and insert them into the first column in another table and the rest in second column:

```
Column 1
-----------------
fvjvnfjd    
kbnjd    
fknbfdbvdfgvrg    
jrfbvfnlopq    
wjasmdf
```

This needs to look like this:

```
Column 1       | Column 2            
---------------|-------------------    
fv             | jvnfjd    
kb             | njd    
fk             | nbfdbvdfgvrg    
jr             | fbvfnlopq    
wj             | asmdf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`left` and `substring` functions  can be used to split the column and insert as two columns in to another table

```
insert into table2
select left(column1,2), substring(column1, 3, len(column1) ) from table1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEFT()` and `STUFF()`:

```
SELECT LEFT(Col1,2) AS Col1
      ,STUFF(Col1,1,2,'') AS Col2
FROM YourTable
```